# Redirect 404 with .htaccess without redirecting trailing slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I want my `.htaccess` file to redirect all 404 pages to the homepage and remove trailing slash on all pages. However, the 404 pages with a trailing slash are getting 2 redirections. How can I fix this?

Now:
`www.example.com/notfound/` --> `www.example.com/notfound` --> `www.example.com`

What I want:
`www.example.com/notfound/` --> `www.example.com`

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.example.com

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Redirecting and/or sending the 404 request to the homepage is generally a bad idea for SEO and usability. Is there a particular reason _why_ you want to do it this way? Knowing your URL structure (and how you route your URLs) would also help to better resolve this. (But 2 redirects isn't necessarily "bad" anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this instead:

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.example.com/

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R,L]
```

Instead of removing the trailing slash when the request does not map to a directory, you only really want to remove the trailing slash when the request (without a trailing slash) maps to a physical file. This then avoids removing the trailing slash on requests that are already 404s.

Your 2nd condition that checked against the `REQUEST_URI` server variable was entirely superfluous.

The redirect to remove a trailing slash should probably be a 301 (permanent), rather than a 302 (temporary) - but that's up to you.

However, to emphasise my comment above, unless you have a specific reason for doing this, *redirecting* to the 404 and/or serving your homepage as the 404 is generally bad for SEO and usability.